# Calculating beta in pine script : what am I doing wrong?

Tags: pine-script

I've written the following pine script code to calculate the beta ratio but I'm getting a result that seems too small to me. I've checked the definition of beta on numerous sites and everything seems correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
//@version=4
study("BETA")

// % change for current symbol close
sym_change = roc(close, 1)

// getting close value for SP500
spx_close = security("SPX", timeframe.period, close)
// % change for SP500 close
spx_change = roc(spx_close, 1)

// arrays get instantiated on first script exec
var sym_chg_arr = array.new_float(0)
var spx_chg_arr = array.new_float(0)

// adding a new value to both arrays for each bar
array.push(sym_chg_arr, sym_change)
array.push(spx_chg_arr, spx_change)

covariance = array.covariance(sym_chg_arr, spx_chg_arr)
variance = array.variance(sym_chg_arr)

beta = covariance / variance

// plotting calculated beta
plot(beta, color=color.yellow, linewidth=2, histbase=0)
// plotting zero line
hline(0)
```

Adding a link to one of the definitions of beta I used to implement the code above https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/102714/how-do-you-calculate-beta-excel.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think your length is the issue.  Yahoo calculate with 5y of data monthly, which would mean a length of 60, for a period "Monthly".

Working on the same right now...

EDIT

I'm able to get the same value as Yahoo Finance ONLY if I'm on the Monthly timeframe.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public 

License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © piram.manickam

//@version=4
study(title='BETA (SPX 5y)', overlay=true)
//Adapted from script written by Ricardo Santos

length = input(61)
smooth = input(1)

return_percent(src) =>
    change(src) * 100 / src[1]

instrument = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", ema(close, smooth))
benchmark = security(input('SP:SPX'), "M", ema(close, smooth))

inst_return = return_percent(instrument)
bench_return = return_percent(benchmark)
avg_inst_return = sma(inst_return, length)
avg_bench_return = sma(bench_return, length)

sum = 0.0
for idx = length to 0
    inst_variance = inst_return[idx] - avg_inst_return
    bench_variance = bench_return[idx] - avg_bench_return
    sum := sum + inst_variance * bench_variance
  
covariance = sum/(length-1)
beta = covariance / variance(bench_return, length)

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Beta is " + tostring(beta))
 
 
//plot(beta)
```

Hope that help !

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and will let you know but in the meantime I discovered that there are really a few different ways to calculate beta and the algo I followed does always return a low beta. If you take a look at this article they also get a small decimal beta value when using the variance-covariance method https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/beta-formula/

Answer (score 0):

[Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13250272/marco) you were correct in that beta provided on various sites such as yahoo finance is calculated using monthly close values and specifically it's on a 5-years interval. Anyhow I also found an error in my script as variance has to be calculated on the benchmark, not on the security. Below the correct script which returns the beta provided by popular sites when timeframe.period = "1M".

```
//@version=4
study("BETA")

// % change for current symbol close
sym_change = roc(close, 1)

// getting close value for SP500
spx_close = security("SPX", timeframe.period, close)
// % change for SP500 close
spx_change = roc(spx_close, 1)

// arrays get instantiated on first script exec
var sym_chg_arr = array.new_float(0)
var spx_chg_arr = array.new_float(0)

// adding a new value to both arrays for each bar
array.push(sym_chg_arr, sym_change)
array.push(spx_chg_arr, spx_change)

// keeping only the last 60 months (5 years)
if(array.size(sym_chg_arr) == 61)
    array.shift(sym_chg_arr)

// keeping only the last 60 months (5 years)
if(array.size(spx_chg_arr) == 61)
    array.shift(spx_chg_arr)

covariance = array.covariance(sym_chg_arr, spx_chg_arr)
variance = array.variance(spx_chg_arr)

beta = covariance / variance

// plotting calculated beta
plot(beta, color=color.yellow, linewidth=2, histbase=0)
// plotting zero line
hline(0)
```